# Mounting as loop device fails with "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock, ..."

Tags: linux, mount, livecd, liveusb, loopback

I tried

`$ mount -o loop ./live-cd.iso /mnt`

on a Live-OS image, which failed:

`mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.`

The image file is not corrupt.

Answer (score 6):

In my case it helped to use `kpartx` (install with `sudo apt-get install kpartx` or `sudo pacman -S multipath-tools` or ...):

`$ sudo kpartx -av live-cd.iso`

which created a loopback device at `/dev/mapper/loop0p1` (might also be at `/dev/loop0p1`) and then I mounted that instead:

`$ sudo mount -o loop /dev/mapper/loop0p1 /mnt`, which worked.